# setting image src from jquery with attr() from a django static directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am new to django and I want to set an image from a static directory to an `<img>` tag via jQuery. I have the below logic:

```
<img id="A">
```

```js
function showProfile(person) {
  $("#A").attr("src", "main/images/portrait/" + person + "1.jpg");
}
```

However, when running the above, the image does not show. with Django static files I usually do:

```
<img id="A" src="{% static "main/images/portrait/whatever.jpg" %}">
```

However, I want to get an image dynamically via jQuery how can this be done?

**Update**

Looking at the console, the error shows that the image is not found because the directory is not found.

> Failed to load resource: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/main/images/portrait/adam2.jpg the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

`/main/images/portraits` is a relative directory in a django static folder. What path should I give the jQuery file?

Comment: The JS/jQuery logic is fine, so it could be that the function isn't being called correctly, or the `person` value doesn't match a valid image, or even there's some error elsewhere in your code. In any case, please check the console for errors and let us know what it says

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are right just checked console and there was an error, I updated my question

Comment: Thanks. The error means that the JS code is working fine. The problem is simply that the image you're trying to show doesn't exist at the URL you've created. Try making the path relative from the site root, eg `/main/images/portrait/...`

Comment: yep you are right i need to go back a couple of parent directories and make the path relative. In my case: .../../../static/main/images/portrait/

Comment: Glad you got it working